# Will OSX devices register to a Raspberry Pi running avahi-daemon

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, bonjour, avahi, plex

I have a Mac Mini on my local network running Plex Media Server on port 32400. The device is going to sleep mode after 1 hour of inactivity. I want the device to wake if a package is sent to it on port 32400.

If I understood it correctly I have to have a [Bonjour Sleep Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy) in the same network, i.e. an AppleTV. I wonder if I can use a Raspberry Pi instead running the `avahi-daemon`? Will the Mac Mini register itself to Avahi running on the Raspberry Pi before sleeping and is it going to get woken up if I send a package on port 32400 to the Mac Mini?

As far as I can see, `avahi-daemon` is a Linux version of Apple's `mDNSResponder` which the Bonjour Sleep Proxies from Apple are running.

Comment: I can confirm you can access your Raspberry PI by hostname instead of ip using avahi-daemon, similar to how you can access your Bonjour Apple devices by hostname. In terms of waking up Apple devices, testing will tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avahi does not currently support sleep proxy, as either a client or server.  So this will not work.

Currently you require some Apple device for a sleep proxy such as Airport, Time Capsule, Apple TV, etc.

I hope to add support for Sleep Proxy into Avahi